# Check a string is convertable to the n-th element of a std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

I have a std::tuple type and need to check if a string can be de-serialized to one of its elements. The index of the element and the string are only known at run time.

My solution (below) almost works but creates compiler errors when using `std::tuple_element`, giving:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple&>

```
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct IsDeserializable {
  static void check(std::size_t idx, std::stringstream& in) {
    IsDeserializable<Tuple, N-1>::check(idx, in);
    if (idx == N-1) {
      typename std::tuple_element<N-1,Tuple>::type tmp;
      in >> tmp;
    }
  }
};

template<class Tuple>
struct IsDeserializable<Tuple, 1> {
  static void check(std::size_t idx, std::stringstream& in) {
    if (idx == 0) {
      typename std::tuple_element<0,Tuple>::type tmp;
      in >> tmp;
    }
  }
};

template<class Tuple>
bool is_deserializable(std::size_t idx, const std::string& val) {
  std::stringstream in;
  in << val;
  try {
    IsDeserializable<Tuple, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>::check(idx, in);
    return true;
  }
  catch(...) {return false;}
} 


// Example Usage
std::tuple<int,double,char> MyTuple;

assert(is_deserializable<MyTuple>(0,"4"));
assert(is_deserializable<MyTuple>(1,"56.5"));
assert(is_deserializable<MyTuple>(2,"h"));

assert(!is_deserializable<MyTuple>(0,"4.3"));
assert(!is_deserializable<MyTuple>(1,"Hello"));
assert(!is_deserializable<MyTuple>(2,"42"));
```

Comment: `tuple_element` needs a tuple type, not a reference type. Just use `Tuple` instead of `Tuple&` (or `typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Xeo. I have updated the code to remove the reference. It did not solve the problem though.

Comment: Adding 'typename' (together with Xeos suggestion) solved the problem!

Comment: One other thing to note is that the code has a bug. It should also check if the whole string has been swallowed to prevent false positives.